# Grouping recursive child elements based on property value

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Here's my example XML. How can I group these `Department` elements using LINQ to XML where each has the attribute `hasLab='1'`?

```
   <ResearchLabs>
  <Departments>
    <Department  hasLab="1">
      <Department hasLab="0">
        <Subject name="Pharma"/>
        <Department hasLab="1">
          <Department hasLab="0">
            <Subject name="Data"/>
          </Department>
        </Department>
      </Department>
      <Department hasLab="0">
        <Subject name="Submission"/>
      </Department>
    </Department>
  </Departments>
</ResearchLabs>
```

Comment: That is one weird looking xml file structure... What exactly do you want to extract out of it?

Comment: A `Department` which is inside a `Department` that is actually inside a `Department` with `Subject`, and that one is inside another `Department` which is inside another `Department`, amazing just amazing.

Comment: @alex the xml structure i have is very complex.The xml you see here is a simplified version of it.The solution provided by Jeff Mercado
is the right answer and it solved my problem when i translated that to fit my complex structure.

Comment: simplifying sometimes just creates confusion. It was very hard to tell what you wanted from your initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

This groups all child departments that doesn't have a lab under parent departments that does have a lab.

```
var query = from dept in doc.Descendants("Department")
            where (int)dept.Attribute("hasLab") == 0
               && dept.Parent.Name == "Department" // probably not needed
               && (int)dept.Parent.Attribute("hasLab") == 1
            group dept by dept.Parent;
```

Or an alternative query, probably more efficient:

```
var query = from dept in doc.Descendants("Department")
            where (int)dept.Attribute("hasLab") == 1
            from sub in dept.Elements("Department")
            where (int)sub.Attribute("hasLab") == 0
            group sub by dept;
```

Though I'd prefer not creating a grouping (definitely more efficient):

```
var query = from dept in doc.Descendants("Department")
            where (int)dept.Attribute("hasLab") == 1
            select new
            {
                Parent   = dept,
                Children = dept.Elements("Department")
                               .Where(sub => (int)sub.Attribute("hasLab") == 0),
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but you could use:

```
var grouped = xml.Descendants("Department")
                 .GroupBy(x => (int) x.Attribute("hasLab"));
```

Comment: It's a heirarchial xml data. I want to group all the Departments which has hasLab=1 along with its child departments where hasLab=0.

Comment: It's not about grouping 0 and 1s . Any department that hasLabs=1 is considered to be a parent node and the department within that parent node which has hasLabs=0 is its child.

Comment: @SharpC: Then it's still entirely unclear to me what you want the result to be, I'm afraid.